# How to filter in an array of objects by filter object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, filter

I am quite new in Javascript and I got a simple assignment, which I can't seem to figure out.
So in my assignment have a data array like this:

```
var data = [{
    "category": "catch",
    "Id": "3",
    "name": "Vertball Shoulder Catch"
}, {
    "category": "raise",
    "ID": "4",
    "name": "Vertball Raise",
    "area": ["hamstring", "lowerBack ", "arms"]
}, {
    "category": "slam",
    "ID": "5",
    "name": "Slamball Slams",
    "area": ["upperBack", "neck"]
}, {
    "category": "slam",
    "ID": "6",
    "name": "Slamball Burpee Slam",
    "area": ["hamstring", "lowerback ", "calves"]
}];
```

I need to write a method where I can give the array and an object to filter on, which gives me the matching values from the array back.

So the method has to be something like:

```
myMethod(array, objectToFilterOn){
//the logic

console.log("the results)
}
```

the objectToFilterOn can vary from this:

```
{category:'raise'}
```

or this:

```
{category:"raise", area:["lowerBack"]}
```

or anything that the user would like, these are just examples.
I want it with the input to give back the whole objects that include anything with this.

Can anyone help me fix this problem or send me in the right direction, been stuck on it for a while now?

Comment: Does `area:["shoulders", "hamstring"]` in the object to filter on mean the element has to have at least those areas, either of those areas, or exactly those areas?

Comment: Either those areas

Comment: your method would want: the array, the property and the value to search for and return the object that contained them, right? look into array.filter, which passes the array item (in your case one of the objects) that you can test on to see if the `item[property].indexOf(value) !== -1`

Comment: My method only wants the array and the object which should be filtered on

Comment: Yes, but if you're passing `category:'ball'` as something to filter on, you're actually asking to find the property category and the value 'ball'.

Comment: There are lots of pieces to this answer. Use `filter()` to filter the array. The callback function should use `Array.every()` and Object.entries(objectToFilterOb)` to check each property in the object to filter on.

Comment: It will then need to test whether the value in the object to filter on is an array or string. If it's an array, it needs to check for intersection between the property in the array and the property in the object to filter on.

Comment: Yeah the filter and array.every() I already figured out, but to put them together in a single method is quite the task :(. I am very very new to javascript

Comment: Yes, I am working on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for n-levels-depth filter object.

I've added `"nestedObj": {...}` for last `data` entry, rest without a change.

```js
const data = [{"category":"catch","ID":"003","name":"Vertball Shoulder Catch","area":["hamstring","lower_back ","buttocks"]},{"category":"raise","ID":"004","name":"Vertball Raise","area":["hamstring","lower_back ","buttocks"]},{ "category":"slam","ID":"005","name":"Slamball Slams","area":["shoulders","abdomen"]},
{
    "category": "slam",
    "ID": "006",
    "name": "Slamball Burpee Slam",
    "area": ["hamstring", "lower_back", "buttocks"],
    "nestedObj": {
      "name": "Tod",
      "nestedArea": ["dum", "bum"]
    }
}]

const filterByObject = (array, obj) => array.filter(e => 
  Object.entries(obj).every(([k, v]) => { switch(true) {
    case e[k] === v: // primitives equalition
      return true
    case Array.isArray(v): // arrays equaltion
      return v.every(x => e[k].includes(x))
    case typeof v === 'object': // recursive repeat if object
      return filterByObject(Object.entries(e[k]), v)
    default: return false // unhandled case (maybe there is any)
  }})
)

const filterObj = {
  category: "slam",
  area: ["hamstring", "buttocks"],
  nestedObj: {
    name: "Tod",
    nestedArea: ["dum"]
  }
}

const res = filterByObject(data, filterObj)

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
    "category": "catch",
    "ID": "003",
    "name": "Vertball Shoulder Catch",
    "area": ["hamstring", "lower_back ", "buttocks"]
}, {
    "category": "raise",
    "ID": "004",
    "name": "Vertball Raise",
    "area": ["hamstring", "lower_back ", "buttocks"]
}, {
    "category": "slam",
    "ID": "005",
    "name": "Slamball Slams",
    "area": ["shoulders", "abdomen"]
}, {
    "category": "slam",
    "ID": "006",
    "name": "Slamball Burpee Slam",
    "area": ["hamstring", "lower_back ", "buttocks"]
}];


const objectToFilterOn = {
    category: 'slam',
    area: ["abdomen", "hamstring"]
}

function myMethod(array, objectToFilterOn) {
    const result = array.filter(el => {
        for (let key in objectToFilterOn) {
            if (Array.isArray(objectToFilterOn[key])) {
                if (el.hasOwnProperty(key) && Array.isArray(el[key])) {
                    for (let strIndex in objectToFilterOn[key]) {
                        if (el[key].find(s => s === objectToFilterOn[key][strIndex])) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!el.hasOwnProperty(key) || (el[key] !== objectToFilterOn[key])) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    });

    return result;
}

console.log(myMethod(data, objectToFilterOn));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use javascript Array `filter` method to filter your input array

```
data.filter(obj => obj.category === objectToFilterOn.category 
|| obj.ID === objectToFilterOn.ID 
|| obj.name === objectToFilterOn.name 
|| obj.areas?.some(el =>  objectToFilterOn?.includes(el)));
```

Comment: Matching the object to filter on needs to be more dynamic. Look at his two examples.

Comment: Yeah but I do not know for sure if the user gives me an object that has a category in it. It could be I only get the ID, or only the name.

Comment: This won't work correctly if any of the criteria are missing in `objectToFilterOn`

Comment: @Barmar Why won't work if missing? I have included all the criteria. If they are `undefined` the corresponding condition will be false and as it's || so it will check other conditions. So if only id is passed other's will be false while id condition will be matched.