# Check if one object is another object's descendent

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to check if an object is another object's descendent. For example, obj2 is obj1's descendent:

```
const obj1 = {
  a: 100,
  b: {
    c:{
      d:100,
      e:200,
      f:3,
      g:50,
      h:10,
      i:{
        j:{
          x:50,
          y:100
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
const obj2 = {
  i:{
    j:{
      x:50,
      y:100
    }
    
  }
}
```

I try to use recursion to check this, but it's not correct. May I know where is the mistake? Thank you so much!

```
function isDescendent(obj1,obj2) {
  //if both not object, compare their value
  if (typeof obj1 !== 'object' && typeof obj2 !== 'object') {
    return obj1 === obj2;
  }
  //if both object, compare their length first 
  if(Object.keys(obj1).length !== Object.keys(obj2).length) {
    return false;
  }
   
  //if both object with the same length, loop and compare each key 
  for (let key in obj1) {
    if(isDescendent(obj1[key],obj2)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter in an array of objects by filter object in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67693645/how-to-filter-in-an-array-of-objects-by-filter-object-in-javascript)

Comment: @ulou hi!Thanks for the reply! That seems different.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a simple type analysis on parent input, `T`, and descendant input, `t` -

```js
function isSubset (T, t)
{ if (T?.constructor !== t?.constructor)
    return false
  else switch (t?.constructor)
  { case Object:
      return Object.keys(t).every(k => isSubset(T[k], t[k]))
        || Object.keys(T).some(k => isSubset(T[k], t))
    default:
      return T === t
  }
}

const a = {a:100,b:{c:{d:100,e:200,f:3,g:50,h:10,i:{j:{x:50,y:100}}}}}
const b = {i:{j:{x:50,y:100}}}

console.log(isSubset(a, b))              // true
console.log(isSubset(a, {y: 100}))       // true
console.log(isSubset(a, {y: 100, x:50})) // true

console.log(isSubset(a, {y: "100"})) // false
console.log(isSubset(a, {y: 99}))    // false
console.log(isSubset(a, {z: 100}))   // false
```

If the `constructor` for `T` and `t` do not match, we return `false` -

```js
if (T?.constructor !== t?.constructor)
  return false
// ...
```

Otherwise we do a type analysis on `t`. If `t` is an Object, `isSubset(T, t)` is true only if `every` key, `k`, in `t` has as a value that matches `T[k]` **or** `some` key, `k`, in `T` has a value that matches `t` -

```js
// ...
else (switch t?.constructor)
{ case Object:
    return Object.keys(t).every(k => isSubset(T[k], t[k]))
      || Object.keys(T).some(k => isSubset(T[k], t))
// ...
```

For all other types, compare `T` to `t` directly using strict equality -

```js
  // ...
  default:
    return T === t
  // ...
```

Note this answer is easily adapted to add support for Array-based inputs as well. We simply add `case Array` to the type analysis and it can behave exactly the same as Objects -

```js
function isSubset (T, t)
{ // ...
  else switch (t?.constructor)
  { case Object:
    case Array:      // <- or Arrays
      return // ...
    default:
      // ...
  }
}
```

Whatever you do, do **not** use `JSON.stringify` for object comparison. Objects are unordered so you cannot reliably compare them using serialization -

```js
const one = { a: 1, b: 2 }
const two = { b: 2, a: 1 }

console.log(JSON.stringify(one) == JSON.stringify(two))
// false
```

Comment: What if both constructors are something else other than `Object`. Or what if they are created with `Object.create(null)`?

Comment: If you have custom classes or objects, they can (should) define their own comparison logic. Or they can hand off their internal state to this generic `isSubset` function. Ie, `myObj.isSubset(myObj2)` includes and passes internal state to `isSubset`.  To promote the highest degree of reusability, classes should be *thin* (dumb) wrappers around plain functions that operate on ordinary data. Otherwise you end up duplicating the same features in every class that requires it. For concrete examples, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66340109/633183)

Comment: I don't think the user cares much about specific comparison rules between objects with the same constructor but he'll have to clarify that. I still think it'd be best to check if it's an object with `typeof`. You could then have your switch for the object constructors.

Comment: You have it backwards. Generic functions such as `+` or `concat` cannot be made aware of any custom objects, or new types that come into existence in the future. However it's trivial to have a custom user object send internal data to `+` or `concat` without requiring the user to re-implement these features.

Comment: A perfect example of this is `toJSON` where the user doesn't have to reimplement JSON serialization from scratch. Instead, the user defines a `toJSON` function on their object (or in their class) and sends returns the relevant internal state to be serialized. The generic `JSON` modules takes care of the rest.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding me. Your switch has 2 branches. It's either an `Object` or else. You could simply use a simple if condition with `typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null`. You then can use your switch for the constructor. You put your `Object` logic into the `default` case and then you can let him handle any other specific case.

Comment: @Thankyou Thank you so much for your help! May I know what does "?.constructor" mean?  Why we don't write as "T.constructor !== t.constructor" ?  Also, when t is an object, why do we need both "Object.keys(t).every(k => isSubset(T[k], t[k]))" and   "Object.keys(T).some(k => isSubset(T[k], t))" and either of them make it true? Oh and if b = {i:{j:{x:50}}} and y:100 is missing, if we want it return false, what should we do? Sorry I'm new to js and Thank you so much! :D

Comment: `?.constructor` works on `null` and `undefined` otherwise you would have to write `T && t && T.constructor === t.constructor`. The reason for needing both is because you need to match either the _entire_ of `T` or just one of its keys. That's why `isSubset(T, {i:{j:...}})` is true because it is found in one of `T`s keys. Otherwise you would need to wrap `{i:{j:...}}` in `{b:{c:...}}`.

Comment: As for the "missing" `y:100` that is possible with only a small change to this function. What do you think we would need to change to get that kind of behaviour? Give it a try and let me know if you get stuck :D

Answer (score 0):

I've used [lodash](https://lodash.com/) for deep object equality, but you can use any other function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects).

For your case, something like this should work.

```js
const obj1={a:100,b:{c:{d:100,e:200,f:3,g:50,h:10,i:{j:{x:50,y:100}}}}}
const obj2={i:{j:{x:50,y:100}}}

const isNestedObject = (obj, nestedObj) =>
  Object.entries(obj).some(([k, v]) => { switch(true) {
    case Object.keys(nestedObj).includes(k)
      && _.isEqual(nestedObj, {[k]: v}): 
      return true
    case v !== null && typeof v === 'object':
      return isNestedObject(v, nestedObj)
    default:
      return false 
  }})

const res = isNestedObject(obj1, obj2)

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You may wanna check for null on the `typeof v === 'object'`, but I think otherwise this works.

Comment: Oh I see, give me 30s.

Comment: using `JSON.stringify` to compare objects is unpredictable. Object properties do not have a guaranteed order, so `JSON.stringify({ a: 1, b: 2})` is not equal to `JSON.stringify({ b:2, a:1 })`

Answer (score 0):

My solution assumes non-cyclic objects with primitive value fields. Note that obj2 is not a full sub object of obj1. It only has the key i while c in obj1 has many others.

```js
const obj1 = { a: 100, b: { c:{ d:100, e:200, f:3, g:50, h:10, i:{ j:{ x:50, y:100 } } } } };
const obj2 = { i:{ j:{ x:50, y:100 } } };
const obj3 = { j:{ x:50, y:100 } };

const enumerateSubObjects = o => {
  const heads = [ o ];
  const subObjects = [];
  while( heads.length ) {
    const current = heads.shift();
    subObjects.push( current );
    if( typeof current === 'object' ) {
      heads.push( ...Object.values( current ) );
    }
  }
  
  return subObjects;
}

const equals = (a, b) => typeof a !== 'object' || typeof b !== 'object'
    ? typeof a === typeof b && a == b
    : Object.keys(a).length == Object.keys(b).length 
      && Object.keys(a).every( key => equals( a[key], b[key] ) );

const isNested = (a, b) =>
  enumerateSubObjects(a).some( subObject => equals( subObject, b ) );

console.log(isNested(obj1, obj2));
console.log(isNested(obj1, obj3));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your recursive function, you can first check if all the keys of the descendent appear in `obj1`. If they do, then the recursion can occur on `obj1`'s values for each key in the descendent. If not, the recursion can be applied to all the values of `obj1`:

```js
function isDescendent(obj1, obj2){
   if (!Object.keys(obj2).every(x => x in obj1)){
      return Object.keys(obj1).some(x => (typeof obj1[x] === typeof obj2) && isDescendent(obj1[x], obj2))
   }
   return Object.keys(obj2).every(function(x){
       if (typeof obj1[x] === 'object' && typeof obj2[x] === 'object'){
          return isDescendent(obj1[x], obj2[x])
       }
       return obj1[x] === obj2[x]
   });
}
const a = {a:100,b:{c:{d:100,e:200,f:3,g:50,h:10,i:{j:{x:50,y:100}}}}}
const b = {i:{j:{x:50,y:100}}}
console.log(isDescendent(a, b)) 
console.log(isDescendent(a, {y: 100}))
console.log(isDescendent(a, {y: 100, x:50}))
console.log(isDescendent(a, {y: "100"}))
console.log(isDescendent(a, {y: 99}))
console.log(isDescendent(a, {z: 100}))
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you want to know if obj1 is inherited from obj2, sorry if I'm wrong, but if I'm not then what you could do is check for their ****proto**** property, so what you could do is

```
function isDescendent(obj1, obj2){
if(obj1.__proto==obj2.__proto__)
     {
            //Do something
     }
}
```

What this code actually does is check for the proto property as I mentioned above, so if they are equal this means that, the object1 is inherited from object2  or is a descendant of object2 in your case....
I don't know how to solve it with recursion but if you are willing to go for a simpler solution this is the one you should go with..